# "Dataset not found in location" error message when running scheduled query

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a dataset located in Europe-west3, and i'm trying to setup scheduled queries on that dataset. However, when setting up the scheduled query, the "processing location" option doesn't contain Europe-west3 as an option. Leaving it as "default" makes the processing location be US, and then the query is unable to run. There are only like 7 procesing locations available, i tried both EU and Europe-west2, but neither work.

I don't really know what to do to get my queries to run on schedule. I can run the queries just fine normally, but trying to schedule them the processing location simply wont let me pick the correct location.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently Schedule Queries does not support region europe-west3. Follow (star) [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/148453096) public issue tracker to stay updated.

Right now if you need to implement scheduled queries you should create a replica of that dataset in another region that is supported and run them there. I would suggest creating a [copy](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#setting_up_a_dataset_copy) of that dataset in another region. However, this feature is also [not available](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/copying-datasets#location_limitations) for region europe-west3 right now.

I hope you can achieve what you desire without many headaches.

Comment: Alright thanks. Going to be a major headache for me sadly, as i have several programs pointing at this dataset. But i thought that might've been the case. Thanks :)